# How to remove this black stuff at my countertop corner joint

Tags: cleaning, caulk, stain-removal

Wondering if anyone has tips on how to properly remove and clean this. I've got scrubbers, soap, but they didn't really work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like mildew behind silicone caulk. I'd scrape it away with a putty knife and razor blade, taking care to not damage the surface. Then use a mild abrasive cleaner to buff away the stain. Consult the surface manufacturer for products and procedures.

Re-caulk with pure silicone after a good drying interval. Use as small a bead as possible for the best appearance.

Comment: You can also get plastic razor blades which can work well and have less chance of damaging surface.  For stain on quartz the magic eraser is good just try it on a test area to make sure it isn't going to look crazy.

Comment: Good suggestions. I have seen Magic Eraser do amazing things, but I've also seen it take painted stripes off an oven control panel. Use due caution.

Comment: Indeed... Magic Eraser is one of those products you really, really, really should obey the "test on a small, inconspicuous area" instruction.